# Var value within JSON output

Tags: php, json

How do I pass a var alue within a Json response?

Trying this but didnt make it work.

```
$code = $_POST['inputCode'];
$output = json_encode(array(//create JSON data
  'type' => 'error',
  'text' => $code
      ));
```

die($output);

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you ask. Yes, the function `json_encode()` is perfect for generating JSON data. You can throw in everything you want. So what is the question? Note that there is no special kind of "JSON data" or a specific structure required.

Comment: Your code looks fine. It should run without any errors, no matter what's the value of `$code`. Do you see any error messages? Try with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` so PHP outputs all errors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I dont see any errors, this is why I thought I was doing something wrong.